# Create a dictionary of columns ( with parts ) from a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe with survey details. Below is a brief extract of the columns:

```
`['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q5', 'Q6', 'Q7', 'Q9', 'Q10', 'Q12_MULTIPLE_CHOICE', 
'Q13_Part_1', 'Q13_Part_2', 'Q13_Part_3', 'Q13_Part_4', 'Q13_Part_5', 
'Q13_Part_6', 'Q13_Part_7', 'Q13_Part_8', 'Q13_Part_9', 'Q13_Part_10', 
'Q13_Part_11', 'Q13_Part_12', 'Q13_Part_13', 'Q13_Part_14', 'Q13_Part_15', 
'Q15_Part_1', 'Q15_Part_2', 'Q15_Part_3', 'Q15_Part_4', 'Q15_Part_5', 
'Q15_Part_6', 'Q15_Part_7']`
```

I want to create a dictionary that holds 'questions with parts', that is, key to the dictionary will be the question number, and value will b a list of parts.

Eg:

```
mydict= {
     'Q13': ['Q13_Part_1', 'Q13_Part_2',... ],
     'Q15': ['Q15_Part_1', 'Q15_Part_2', 'Q15_Part_3', 'Q15_Part_4', 
     'Q15_Part_5', 'Q15_Part_6', 'Q15_Part_7'],
      ..
    }
```

How may i approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for storage values:

```
L = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q5', 'Q6', 'Q7', 'Q9', 'Q10', 'Q12_MULTIPLE_CHOICE', 
'Q13_Part_1', 'Q13_Part_2', 'Q13_Part_3', 'Q13_Part_4', 'Q13_Part_5', 
'Q13_Part_6', 'Q13_Part_7', 'Q13_Part_8', 'Q13_Part_9', 'Q13_Part_10', 
'Q13_Part_11', 'Q13_Part_12', 'Q13_Part_13', 'Q13_Part_14', 'Q13_Part_15', 
'Q15_Part_1', 'Q15_Part_2', 'Q15_Part_3', 'Q15_Part_4', 'Q15_Part_5', 
'Q15_Part_6', 'Q15_Part_7']


from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for x in L:
    if '_' in x:
        d[x.split('_')[0]].append(x)
print (d)


defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Q12': ['Q12_MULTIPLE_CHOICE'], 
                             'Q13': ['Q13_Part_1', 'Q13_Part_2', 'Q13_Part_3', 'Q13_Part_4', 
                                     'Q13_Part_5', 'Q13_Part_6', 'Q13_Part_7', 'Q13_Part_8',
                                     'Q13_Part_9', 'Q13_Part_10', 'Q13_Part_11', 'Q13_Part_12',
                                     'Q13_Part_13', 'Q13_Part_14', 'Q13_Part_15'], 
                             'Q15': ['Q15_Part_1', 'Q15_Part_2', 'Q15_Part_3', 'Q15_Part_4',
                                     'Q15_Part_5', 'Q15_Part_6', 'Q15_Part_7']})
```

---

```
print (dict(d))

{'Q12': ['Q12_MULTIPLE_CHOICE'], 
 'Q13': ['Q13_Part_1', 'Q13_Part_2', 'Q13_Part_3', 'Q13_Part_4', 
         'Q13_Part_5', 'Q13_Part_6', 'Q13_Part_7', 'Q13_Part_8', 
         'Q13_Part_9', 'Q13_Part_10', 'Q13_Part_11', 'Q13_Part_12',
         'Q13_Part_13', 'Q13_Part_14', 'Q13_Part_15'],
 'Q15': ['Q15_Part_1', 'Q15_Part_2', 'Q15_Part_3',
         'Q15_Part_4', 'Q15_Part_5', 'Q15_Part_6', 'Q15_Part_7']}
```